# Ipfs.files.add promise throws error

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ipfs

I'm trying to upload a simple image file to IPFS using `ipfs.files.add()`. However, I can't seem to figure out why the promise throws an error.

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {

    const IPFS = require("ipfs-api");
    const ipfs = IPFS("localhost", "5001", {protocol: "http"});

    var fileBuffer;
    var imageUpload = document.getElementById("input");
    imageUpload.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);

    function handleFiles() {
      console.log("File Chosen!");
      const reader = new FileReader;
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(imageUpload.files[0]);
      console.log("Buffering...")
      reader.onload = function() {
        var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
        fileBuffer = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        console.log("Buffer: ", fileBuffer);
        ipfsUpload();
      }
    }

    function ipfsUpload() {
      console.log("Uploading...");
      ipfs.files.add(fileBuffer, (error, result) => {
        if (error || !result) {
          console.log("Error!");
        }
        else {
          console.log("Success!");
        }

      });
    }

  });
});
```

At first I thought I wasn't properly connected to my IPFS node. However, I did the whole process in the terminal window with node.js and it worked. So I'm thinking this might have something to do with the browser (Chrome) or some dependency?

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "browserify": "^16.2.2",
    "buffer": "^5.2.0",
    "ipfs": "^0.31.6",
    "ipfs-api": "^24.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "truffle": "^4.1.14",
    "web3": "^0.20.7"
  }
```

Note: I'm using Browserify to bundle all my dependencies.

EDIT: After printing the actual error, I get the following:

```
TypeError: content.once is not a function
    at Multipart._pushFile (bundle.js:29092)
    at Multipart._maybeDrain (bundle.js:29056)
    at Multipart._transform (bundle.js:29048)
    at Multipart.Transform._read (bundle.js:107644)
    at Multipart.Transform._write (bundle.js:107632)
    at doWrite (bundle.js:108104)
    at writeOrBuffer (bundle.js:108093)
    at Multipart.Writable.write (bundle.js:108010)
    at eachSeries (bundle.js:29443)
    at bundle.js:23065
```

Comment: You should print the actual error instead of `"Error!"`, it might give you (and us, if you add the output to your question) more information about what's going on

Comment: @Henk I get `TypeError: content.once is not a function`. I added the details in my question.

Comment: @Henk It appears to be some sort of bug which was noticed [a while back](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-api/issues/649) However, I don't quite seem to understand what they did to fix and why I still have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to fix this issue by using `Buffer.from()` on my variable `fileBuffer` in `ipfs.files.add()`, giving me the following code:

```
ipfs.files.add(Buffer.from(fileBuffer), function(error, result) {
        if (error || !result) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        else {
          console.log("Success!");
        }
      });
```